# Running migrations against the Rails test environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I know that I can [run specific migrations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#being-specific):

```
rake db:migrate:up VERSION=20080906120000
```

But can I run a specific migration against my test database? Will the following work?

```
RAILS_ENV=test rake db:migrate:up VERSION=20080906120000
```

In theory, running the migrations in default mode (which should affect the development database) and then running `rake db:test:prepare` should get the job done, but I found something strange with my test database after doing that, and I need to run a specific migration on the test database to aid my troubleshooting.

I'd just try out the above `rake` command, except I'm in the middle of a long data seeding run on my development database, and I can't risk the migration interfering with that, so I figured I'd see if anyone knows the answer before I can determine it myself. :)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

In different order:

```
rake db:migrate:up VERSION=20080906120000 RAILS_ENV=test
```

Comment: does the Rails_ENV have to all be capitalized?

Comment: `RAILS_ENV` is intended to be an environment variable @Jwan622, so I guess, yes. For further info see [Max's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43869192/5025116).

Comment: Yes, it needs to be capitalized; environment variables are case sensitive, so RAILS_ENV and rails_env, etc, are two different environment variables.  Theoretically rails could check for both, but I'm pretty sure it doesn't, because if I try the other way (`rails_env=test`), my tests, etc, fail, when they don't with `RAILS_ENV=test`