# Where is the RAILS_ENV?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm looking at this article about rake commands but don't where the RAILS_ENV is. Is that in a specific file somewhere?

```
db:create Creates the database for the current RAILS_ENV environment. If RAILS_ENV is not specified it defaults to the development and test databases.
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`RAILS_ENV` is just an environmental variable which is set in the shell or the operating system itself (or when invoking the process).

> Environment variables are a set of dynamic named values that can
>   affect the way running processes will behave on a computer.
>   They are part of the environment in which a process runs. For example, a
>   running process can query the value of the `TEMP` environment variable
>   to discover a suitable location to store temporary files, or the `HOME`
>   or `USERPROFILE` variable to find the directory structure owned by the
>   user running the process.
>   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable

`ENV["RAILS_ENV"]` simply contains a string such as "production", "development" or "test". This tells Rails [which configuration file](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html) in `/config/environments` to load - and which hash key in `database.yml` to use for the database.

For example if `ENV["RAILS_ENV"] == "foo"` Rails will:

- load `/config/environments/foo.rb`
- look for the key `foo` in database.yml.
- `Rails.env.foo?` will be true.

The Rails concept of environment is thus somewhat different than the general computing concept - a Rails environment is a broader term for a set of settings and a database that serve different purposes such as automated testing or production.

See also:

- [Store config in the environment](https://12factor.net/config)

Comment: How exactly to set ENV vars depends on the shell used and the operating system. Most OS:es (even windows) do have env vars though.

Comment: We are in production. Our app runs production. But if we echo RAILS_ENV, it is empty. That means it should default to development. But our app really really runs production. How come?

Answer (score 2):

It's the environment variable you can set by passing it before the command you are executing

```
RAILS_ENV=production rake db:migrate
```

You can also set some other ENV variables by passing them before the command

```
MAIL_USERNAME=user MAIL_PASSWORD=password rails server
```

Or you can export them to shell

```
export MAIL_USERNAME=user
export MAIL_PASSWORD=password
rails server
```

There is also a gem called [**`dotenv`**](https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv) which help you set env variables easily by saving them in a `.env` file which will not be pushed over `git` or whatever SVN you use

Comment: so the RAILS_ENV is used as a container for you to build a database to test things out? So you can have multiple RAILS_ENV to try having different tables inside? Or would you just keep dropping and re-setuping tables in your dev environment?

Comment: Not exactly what you are thinking..
but yes you can have different environments as per your need like `test`, `demo`, `development` and `production`

Comment: You can also create whatever environments you want just make sure you have `config/environments/#{environment_name}.env`

Comment: so the db in each env will be different?

Comment: yes, and you need to specify the database name environment wise in `database.yml`

Comment: It can be same if you are passing same db name for two environments

Comment: but it's not recommended

Answer (score 1):

RAILS_ENV this is just the name of an environment variable. So it could be used when you run any rake tasks or rails command. Like:

```
RAILS_ENV=test rails c
```

But you will wonder how this env variable be used in Rails, Here is the place:
https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/ce4d467f7c2fc812e257a87bd4875c1f1f08a981/railties/lib/rails.rb#L72

That means Rails will prefer to use RAILS_ENV to decide the current env.

Answer (score 0):

RAILS_ENV is rails environment ie development, production or staging.

You can run commands for different environments using `RAILS_ENV` like:

```
RAILS_ENV=production rake db:migrate #runs migration in production env

RAILS_ENV=test rake db:migrate #runs migration in test env
```

By default environment is development.

Answer (score -1):

To my understanding, this "RAILS_ENV" seems much like environment variable which might be OS level (say under *uix environment, using env to check its value) or maybe it specific to the run-time which might get set in configuration file (.propertie or else).